# How do I resize images and divs in a responsive design?

Tags: responsive-design

I have hacked together a filterable portfolio with thumbnails on one page and a variation of it on my homepage. Problem is when I resize the browser on the homepage, the thumbnails don't resize the same way they do on the portfolio page. Instead on the homepage they break into two columns, then one as the browser shrinks. 
I have been pulling my hair out over this - any suggestions? Thanks!

Homepage - http://riverso.marketplicity.com/

Portfolio Page - http://riverso.marketplicity.com/representative-projects/

*Resize the browser to about 960px on each of the page to see the differences.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please **put your code in the question**, to avoid broken links in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
img
{
        max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please add some commentary. Code-only answers are discouraged.